# Zoom Meeting Default Monitor

Tags: zoom-meeting

Zoom meetings open by default in a certain monitor.
At some point I had this set to my 2nd monitor to open automatically.
But I accidentally moved the window pre-startup to a different monitor and now it opens on my primary monitor.

How can we change zoom meetings to open by default to a specific monitor?
After I move zoom to a certain window it forgets the preference and just opens it in the primary/default place it wants to. This applies to the zoom scheduling window, meeting window, and even the dual monitor window.

I tried scouring the help but it seems like nobody asked this exact thing before. Very surprising since most people (1) have multiple monitors and (2) have different preferences for zoom meetings to load in by.

Comment: “But I accidentally moved the window pre-startup to a different monitor and now it opens on my primary monitor.”  Have you tried to reverse the process? It respected your monitor choice before you moved it show if you move it back it should respect that change. I would need to see some screenshots to determine which option would control this behavior

Comment: @Ramhound key word "accidentally"--I was using a script and accidentally moved the pre-loading window or something. I'm really not quite sure what happened. Does moving the meeting window spawn location to a different monitor work if you try with Zoom?